# jQuery: Extract array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `var`contains:

`var flags = {USA, Brazil, Germany, Canada};`

I can get values with number of each key

http://jsfiddle.net/YQSHr/

How to get numbers {1, 2, 3} without setting them in the `var` and starting from 1

`var flags = {USA, Canada, Germany};`

Edit 2: 
Also I have another `var` without `,`

`var flags = 'USA Brazil Germany Canada';`

Comment: You're making `flags` an object, not an array.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Why can't you just initialize the value for each item in the array to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array of strings, you will need to [use square brackets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals):

```
var flags = ["USA", "Canada", "Germany"];
/* or
var flags = 'USA Brazil Germany Canada'.split(' ');
*/
```

Yet for getting the numbers from the indices you will need to add 1, since the array indices are [zero-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering):

```
$.each(flags, function(index, value){
    $('#flags').append('<span>' + value + (index+1) + '</span> ')
});
```

Output:

```
USA1
Canada2
Germany3
```

Comment: what if my var was a sentence, without `,`

Comment: @Naiimim: You can [make it an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) via `flagArray = flagString.split(" ");`

Comment: @Naiimim: What without jQuery? The split (is native js), the loop, or the append?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
var flags = ['USA','Brazil','Germany','Canada'];
```

Then you can iterate over it with

```
$.each(flags, function(key, value){
    var yourkey = key + 1; // Because you want 1 indexed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var flags = ['USA', 'Canada', 'Germany'];

$.each(flags, function(i, country){
    $('#flags').append('<span>' + country + (i += 1) + '</span> ')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ethagnawl/YQSHr/3/

Comment: Why do you increment the variable `i`?

Comment: JS arrays are 0-based and OP's example was using 1-3.

Comment: And if you would output `i` twice you'd use `(i+=1) + country + (i+=1)`?

Comment: You'd want to call `i += 1` once, probably outside the method call. Then, you could use `i + country + i` when constructing the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var flags = ['USA', 'Canada', 'Germany'];

$.each(flags, function(key, value){
   $('#flags').append('<span>' + (key+1) + ' '+ value + '</span> ')
});
```

Set an array with strings

[DEMO VIEW](http://jsfiddle.net/YQSHr/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not valid.

```
var flags = {USA, Brazil, Germany, Canada};//error
```

Please look up how to use objects or arrays and choose one instead of a mix. This will solve the issue you are having. As others have pointed out in the answers, you will be able to use an array of strings to match with an index, or use indexes in an object to match with the strings.

This would basically mean changing flags to

```
var flags = ["USA","Brazil","Germany","Canada"];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YQSHr/6/

---

However, depending on how many flags you are using you may want to use a data structure.

```
var flagHolder = (function(){
 var flags = [];
 var flagIndex = 0;
 function addFlag(name){
  var flag = {};
  flag.name = name;
  flag.index = flagIndex++;
  flags.push(flag);
  return flag.index;
 }
 function getFlag(index){
  return flags[index];
 }
 function getAllFlags(){
  return flags;
 }
 return { 
  getAllFlags: getAllFlags,
  getFlag: getFlag,
  addFlag: addFlag
 };
})();
```

Which could be used like this:

```
var USA = flagHolder.addFlag("USA");
var Canada = flagHolder.addFlag("Canada");
var Germany = flagHolder.addFlag("Germany");
var Brazil = flagHolder.addFlag("Brazil");
//Get Single
$("#flag").html(flagHolder.getFlag(USA).name);
//Get All
$.each(flagHolder.getAllFlags(), function(key,value){
 $('#flags').append('<span>' + (key+1) + '</span> ');
});
```

Here is a demo for that: http://jsfiddle.net/YQSHr/7/

Comment: Nice, but overkill I'd say :-)

Comment: @Bergi - I know :) But I just figured a one liner was underkill and somehow ended up with this :P